# Terminology for a class who has something as a member

Tags: c++, class, oop, language-agnostic, member

In object oriented programming terminology, I can simply say:

```
- Member: I mean to say a member of (this) class (which I'm referring to)
```

But I don't know what is the correct terminology for this:

```
-   ?   : I mean to say a class who has (this thing I'm referring to) as a member
```

Maybe I can use `owner` or `parent`. Any idea?

Comment: The "surrounding class"?

Comment: @Sweeper Just to clarify, is it official terminology or just a suggestion?

Comment: I don't know what the "official" terminology is (not for C++ anyway), but I know that saying that will probably get your point across.

Comment: Common terms are "owner" or "container/containing class"

Comment: A member is a variable, this may be a constant or a variable that you can change, it is used to store a value.  A member can have access types which can determine how accessible it is in the class, public (not advisable, anyone can access), private (only accessible by the class itself), protected (like private, but also accessible by derived classes and friends).  Every member has an owner in C++ referred to as 'this' which is the class it is defined in.

Comment: Why do you think there should be a term for it? You have 2 hands (I presume) these are part of you. What are you to your hands? Owner? Hardly. "Attributes" (in Meyer's notation) are part of the class, they are class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW the C++ standard calls this "containing object" or "containing class object" in a couple of places. It never formally defines the term though.

I guess you can call the corresponding class "the containing class".

Answer (score 1):

In good old days there was a term **nesting** used in a variety of ways( **nesting scope**, **nesting namespace**, **nesting class**, **nesting function**...). I don't know if it is still widely used, but IMHO it does the purpose.

Regards,

FM.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this as the most clear:

> ... classes which own this class as member ...

Comment: I use this phrase only twice in the whole project. If it is used more often, I think I should use `owner` or some other short word as suggested by others.